# How would I calculate the percentage vote of 18-24 year olds from this infographic

Tags: probability, statistics

[How would I calculate the percentage vote of 18-24 year olds from this infographic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSz6s.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant unless you know the amount of 20-24 year old's and the number of 18-19 year old's.
if you did know you could add up the amount of people of age 18-19 and 20-24 that did vote and divide by the total amount of 18-24 year old's and the multiply by 100 to get a percentage (cant comment yet sorry)

Answer (score 1):

From this infographic, you cannot.

Percentage vote is computed by # of people who voted divided by size of population.

You do not know the individual populations of $18-19$ year olds and $20-24$ year olds.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that, while you can't compute the percent you want exactly, you can certainly come close.

Let's say that of the people in the $18-24$ bracket, $p$ percent are in $18-19$ (so $1-p$ percent are in $20-24$).  Then the answer is $$x=p\times 57+(1-p)\times 59$$

Easy to see that this means the answer you want is between $57$ and $59$...a very tight band!  Indeed $$x=p\times 57 +(1-p)\times 57 +(1-p)*2=57+(1-p)\times 2$$

If, say, we imagine that each year of age has roughly the same number of people in it, then $p\approx \frac 26 \implies x\approx 57+\frac 46\times 2 = 58.\overline 3$ but of course this is an extra assumption.